# Gravity in iOS like in android

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is there any easy way to center controls in a view in iOS like using android:gravity="center_horizontal" in android? I could calculate the position for each control before adding it and recalculate when the screen is rotated, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Use a `UIStackView`.

Comment: I haven't developed for Android before, so I can't make a definitive judgement myself, but would just adding a centering constraint or two with AutoLayout do the trick?

Comment: UIStackView should be the default tool for laying out views. It then deals with any rotation or screen size hanged for you.

Comment: @Fogmeister that's far too general, There are so many situations where a UIStackView isn't appropriate, I don't think we use it in any of our iOS applications to be honest, just haven't had the need for it. Personally I'd use centering constraints and rely on auto layout to do the clever stuff for you.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt the words I used are literally straight from Apple. Yes it can’t do everything. But it can do a lot and should be the starting point of laying out views. Falling back to auto layout constraints if needed.

Comment: @Fogmeister ooof, don't rely on Apple ;)

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I don’t. But having used CGRect layouts, Auto Layout, and UIStackView I have found that UIStackView does 95% of what is required for laying out views. The rest provided by raw AutoLayout. :-)

Comment: The UIStackView seems to be the answer, but how can I add let's say 3 controls and keep them in the center? I tried all combinations of alignment and distribution and all I've got was just one control centered, one in the left and one in the right.

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention, layout_gravity is different from gravity in Android.

**layout_gravity** is for the alignment in container view and **gravity** for the content alignment in self.

After reading your question, I think you mean layout_gravity not gravity.

Okay, Let's discuss about UIStackView.

[What is UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) ,as the documentation said , it is just a container view which can control the distribution, aligment, spacing ,xxx on its subviews, and is created with autoLayout, it means you don't need to manage those constraints on the subviews.

[image]

As you see, the alignment of stackView will apply to all the controls on it not single one.

To achieve the effect like layout_gravity , you have to manage the constraints manually .

[image]

and the constraints on the center button .

[image]

Comment: I know the difference between layout_gravity and gravity, and I need something like gravity. If I apply this on a view I want all the controls inside this view to be centered(this is gravity), not the view being centered in it's parent(like layout_gravity).

Comment: ok , i misunderstand , so UIStackView can solve your peoblem , you just need to set UIStackViewAlignment to Center.

Comment: When the Axis of stack view is Horizontal , you only can set top ,bottom , center , the same reason, when in vetical, only Leading, Trailing can take  effect.